# Transcript vs script

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I am going to present a slideshow in a few days' time.

I am going to start writing out now what I will be saying in this presentation.

Should this written document be called a script or a transcript?

Comment: This appears to be an on-topic question to me. While it does concern the meaning of a word (or, at least, the distinction between two words in a specific context), the answer is *not* something that most non-native speakers could trivially figure out from the dictionary definitions of ["script"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/script) and ["transcript"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transcript). I would vote to reopen this question, but I don't actually have enough rep for that here on ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be called a **script**, because you are writing it before your presentation.

A transcript is a:

> written or printed version of material originally presented in another medium.

This means that if someone in the audience wrote down everything that you said during your presentation, they would have produced a transcript of it.

Use **script** if you are writing down something that will be said in the future, and transcript if you are writing down something that has already been said (as a rule of thumb).

Answer (score 7):

It's really a matter of precise nuance. In general, if you write your text *before* repeating those words verbally in the presentation, it's a ***script***. If the text is written *during* or *after* the presentation (by faithfully [***transcribing***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transcribe) the words you actually said), it's a ***transcript***.

Answer (score 1):

If you start out by writing the text first, you will be writing a script for your slideshow. On the other hand, if the text is written based on an existing presentation, it's a transcript.